# Driver Compilation Redhat

Tags: linux, compilation, driver, redhat

I'm totally new to compiling drivers for linux and I got some problems !

I'm trying to compile a driver for a usb device.

Result:

```
[thayoz@lacalpc13 linux]$ make
for i in driver lib qrng ; do cd $i && (make all || exit ) && cd ..; done
make[1]: Entering directory /home/thayoz/Desktop/untitled folder/Quantis-USB/src/linux/driver'
make -C /usr/src/kernels/ M=/home/thayoz/Desktop/untitled folder/Quantis-USB/src/linux/driver V=1 modules
make[2]: Entering directory/usr/src/kernels'
make[2]: * No rule to make target folder/Quantis-USB/src/linux/driver'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory/usr/src/kernels'
make[1]: * [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/thayoz/Desktop/untitled folder/Quantis-USB/src/linux/driver'
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: lib: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: qrng: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I don't know what's wrong ???

Comment: I assume the kernel source is not in /usr/src/kernels/ but in a subdirectory. you'll need to correct your makefile accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically something like:

```
make -C <directory to kernel source> M=<directory to module/driver source> modules
make -C <directory to kernel source> M=<directory to module/driver source> modules_install
```

is sufficient.

Did your driver come with a makefile?  Are you compiling against the proper kernel sources, the right version, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

I think that space in the path to your build directory might be causing the problem.

/home/thayoz/Desktop/untitled folder/Quantis-USB...

Notice the space in 'untitled folder'.

It looks like make is taking the module directory as:

/home/thayoz/Desktop/untitled

And:

folder/Quantis-USB/src/linux/driver

is getting passed to make as an additional argument (probably a target to be built).

Try renaming '/home/thayoz/Desktop/untitled folder' to '/home/thayoz/Desktop/untitledfolder' and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the general procedure for building a piece of software packaged using the GNU build system is:

1. Run the .configure script. This script checks the build environment on your system, ensuring all the required executables, libraries etc are available and creates a working Makefile.
2. Run make. This uses the Makefile generated in step 1 to build the binary.
3. Run make install. This installs the binary into the correct location on the system.

[GNU Build System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system)

Have you run the .configure script that came with the driver package?

Comment: You're thinking of ./configure (ie the name is just configure and the ./ specifies that it's in the current directory, not to be searched in the PATH)